# How to check adding all attachments in list item

Tags: workflow, powershell, list-item, attachments

I know that in SharePoint Designer workflow it can be checked when attachments are added, but this isn't so super, because when there is some attachment in the list item and someone forgot to add other attachment, then workflow can't check this. So is it possible to check this e.g. via PowerShell?

Comment: You want to check for how many attachments?

Comment: It will work like question with attachment and answer with attachment. So mostly only one more.

Comment: Assuming you are doing 2013 workflow. why don't you check the attachment count in workflow? please use rest api to fetch the attachment file count.. Hope this link helps you...https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/SharePoint/en-US/4a713364-7cf4-4bf0-aafe-7c97b00b7baa/workflow-to-count-the-number-of-items-in-a-list?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, now I use jquery function in new and edit form:

```
function PreSaveAction()  
{  
    var elm = document.getElementById("idAttachmentsTable");  
    if (elm == null || elm.rows.length == 0)  
        {  
                document.getElementById("idAttachmentsRow").style.display='none';  
        var r=confirm("some text");  
            if (r==false) {  
                return false;  
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }

        }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the `document.getElementById("idAttachmentsRow").style.display='none';` part?